# An alternative to the Video Toaster

Tags: windows, video, commodore

Back in the day, there used to be a product called Video Toaster on Commodore, that was years ahead of anything at the time.

Is there something similar for Windows these days that matches Video Toaster's power, ease of use and features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Video Toaster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Toaster) is still alive and kicking. 
Its latest incarnation is the [NewTek TriCaster](http://newtek.com/tricaster/index.php).

See also the website [Open Video Toaster](http://www.openvideotoaster.org/).

The alternative would be any combination of video hardware and good video editing software.

Comment: Here's a living link to the Video Toaster sources: http://www.discreetfx.com/openvideotoaster.html